# Sticky Notes for a Dual-Booted Setup

Tags: dual-boot, productivity, stickynotes

Is there a way for me to "sync" desktop-like sticky notes across my Windows and Ubuntu partitions?

I saw that there are Google Drive options, but IMO, Google Drive uses too much memory and I hate memory drags.

I also found http://www.cloudstickynotes.com/, but it seems kind of sketchy and unprofessional.  Does anyone have experience with it?

Best